# Gulp: copy files from multiple folders into one

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp task:

```
var src = ["Scripts/App/Components/**/*.png"];

gulp.task("images", function () {
    return gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```

This code generates a tree structure:

```
/build
    /Component1
         c1-1.png
    /Component2
         c2-1.png
         c2-2.png
```

But what if I want to merge directories so that all images are in the `/build` directory:

```
/build
    c1-1.png
    c2-1.png
    c2-2.png
```

How do I achieve this using gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`gulp-rename`](https://npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to get rid of the directory name:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var src = ["Scripts/App/Components/**/*.png"];

gulp.task("images", function () {
   return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(rename({dirname:''}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```